# Unable to install several python packages using PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

**Error message:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(27): 
error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'intmax_t'
```

Hi beginner programmer here just want to know and understand what exactly is this error and how to solve it, that I've been getting when installing Python packages, more specifically the newer Python Packages. I've already tried upgrading the pip and setup tools multiple times but still no avail.

*Python version: 3.7*

Comment: You are likely installing a package tgat needs to build some part of code from C and lack a compiler for it. Try work on a command line with pip and post full error trace.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to troubleshoot this using the PyCharm interface.

1. In PyCharm, select File > Preferences > Project > Project Interpreter
2. Under the dropdown menu for project interpreter, ensure you have selected the version of python which you want to run. It is possible you have multiple installs. 
   (If using python 3, ensure that you have updated pip3, not just pip.)
3. Select the '+' button to install packages manually via the interface.

If this does not work directly, it should at least give a somewhat more user friendly platform with which to troubleshoot. If you give more specifics, it may be possible to give more specific advice from there.

> *Note, I am using a Mac, so processes may be altered slightly.*

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 1671: character maps to <undefined>

I'm constantly getting this error whenever i try to download the latest version of package textract. I believe there is something with my configuration of pip and python and Pycharms. Any suggestions on what should I do?

Comment: @JiaYuan Take a look at this page: https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract/issues/190. It seems there is an issue with the latest version of the _textract_ package. Some people have had some success using other branches on the GitHub page for the package.